# copy file and run a particular command using ansible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, ansible-1.x

I need to copy one file into lot of servers and then after copying execute a particular command. Below are the steps I need to do for each machine.

- copy file into a server.
- execute a command (`sudo restart tree`) after copying.
- sleep for few seconds

And repeat above steps for all the machines.

So I decided to use ansible for this. I am able to copy files but I am not sure how can I execute command after copying and then sleep.

I have a `hosts.txt` file which will contain all the machines line by line.

I will login into `machineA` which will have my `function.py` file and `hosts.txt` file and from that machine I will run below `ansible` command.

```
david@machineA:~$ ansible -i hosts.txt -m copy -a "src=function.py dest=/treepot/function.py owner=goldy" -u david --ask-pass --sudo -U root --ask-sudo-pass all
```

With the use of above command, it will copy function.py file but I want to execute `sudo restart tree` command as well after copying that file on each server. So basically

- copy file to machineB.
- then execute the command (sudo restart tree)
- after that sleep for few seconds and then do the same thing for other machines

Can I do this with the use of ansible?  I am running ansible 1.5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suggest use ansible-playbook. here is my example, copy a docker image to 4 hosts, and load it then delete the tar file, maybe it help

```
cat /etc/ansible/hosts
#------------centos-----------  ip is ok(instead of hostname)
[centos]
centos-1
centos-2
centos-3
centos-4

[centos:vars]
ansible_user="root"
```

write a playbook

```
cat load-tar.yaml
- hosts: centos

  tasks:
    - name: copy-image
      copy: src=./elasticsearch.tar dest=/root/elasticsearch.tar

    - name: start docker
      shell: systemctl start docker

    - name: load-image
      shell: docker load < /root/elasticsearch.tar

    - name: delete-file
      file: path="/root/elasticsearch.tar" state=absent
```

and run it

```
ansible-playbook load-tar.yaml
```

Comment: How it will look like in my case? I am very new to ansible things so I don't know much.

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html     . it worth learning if you use ansible

Comment: sure but if you can help me explain with my answer, it will help me understand better. I will go through the link as well but there will be lot of things that now I don't need to understand as a beginner.

Comment: yaml file, host: centos means this will apply to centos group defined in /etc/ansible/hosts.  tasks will execute one by one to all hosts in group. each task has a name( like  copy-image), and a module to like (copy: src=xx,des=xx).